# CUDA thread execution order

Tags: cuda

I have the following code for a CUDA program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_BLOCKS 4
#define THREADS_PER_BLOCK 4

__global__ void hello()
{  

   printf("Hello. I'm a thread %d in block %d\n", threadIdx.x, blockIdx.x);

}


int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    // launch the kernel
    hello<<<NUM_BLOCKS, THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>();

    // force the printf()s to flush
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

in which every thread will print its `threadIdx.x` and `blockIdx.x`. One possible output of this program is this:

```
Hello. I'm a thread 0 in block 0
Hello. I'm a thread 1 in block 0
Hello. I'm a thread 2 in block 0
Hello. I'm a thread 3 in block 0
Hello. I'm a thread 0 in block 2
Hello. I'm a thread 1 in block 2
Hello. I'm a thread 2 in block 2
Hello. I'm a thread 3 in block 2
Hello. I'm a thread 0 in block 3
Hello. I'm a thread 1 in block 3
Hello. I'm a thread 2 in block 3
Hello. I'm a thread 3 in block 3
Hello. I'm a thread 0 in block 1
Hello. I'm a thread 1 in block 1
Hello. I'm a thread 2 in block 1
Hello. I'm a thread 3 in block 1
```

Running the program several times I get similar results, except that block order is random. For example, in the above output we have this block order 0, 2, 3, 1. Running the problem again I get 1,2,3, 0. This is expected. However, the thread order in every block is always 0,1,2,3. Why is this happening? I thought it would be random too.

I tried to change my code to force thread 0 in every block to take longer to execute. I did it like this:

```
__global__ void hello()
{  

    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        int k = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )
        {
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }

   printf("Hello. I'm a thread %d in block %d\n", threadIdx.x, blockIdx.x);

}
```

I would expect thread order to be 1,2,3, 0. However, I got a similar result to the one I have shown above where thread order was always 0, 1, 2, 3. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure that's C language? That should be called something like _C dialect of CUDA_. That's neither C, nor C++.

Comment: ok, agree. I removed that tag to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Your code to try and slow down thread 0 in the last kernel is totally pointless. The compiler is smart enough to just optimise the whole for loop away.

Comment: @talonmies thanks for this comment. Then, running the code with the second kernel is completely equivalent to running the code with the first kernel.

Comment: As per my answer, if you're trying to create "random" output order emanating from threads in a *single* warp, I think that is going to be pretty difficult to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, the thread order in every block is always 0,1,2,3. Why is this happening? I thought it would be random too

With 4 threads per block you are only launching one *warp* per block.  A [warp](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture) is the unit of execution (and scheduling, and resource assignment) in CUDA, not a thread.  Currently, a warp consists of 32 threads.

This means that all 4 of your threads per block (since there is no conditional behavior in this case)  are executing in *lockstep*.  When they reach the `printf` function call, they all execute the call to that function *in the same line of code*, *in lockstep*.

So the question becomes, in this situation, how does the CUDA runtime dispatch these "simultaneous" function calls?  The answer to that question is unspecified, but it is not "random".  Therefore it's reasonable that the order of dispatch for operations within a warp does not change from run to run.

If you launch enough threads to create multiple warps per block, and probably also include some other code to disperse and or "randomize" the behavior between warps, you should be able to see `printf` operations emanating from separate warps occurring in "random" order.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very accurate answer to my question. I marked it as the answer because I learned a lot with it. But may I ask you what happens if I disperse or "randomize" the code. I am interested in understanding the lockstep part further. So suppose thread 0 enters in an if statement and threads 1 to 31 do not (al in the same warp). Assuming threads 1-31 are ready to go on, will they wait for thread 0 to finish the if statement and proceed in lockstep? Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Yes, for an if-then-else construct, all threads in a warp satisfying the if condition will follow the if path, while the remaining threads are "inactive".  Then, the threads satisfying the if condition will be made "inactive", and the threads not satisfying the if condition will be made active, and those threads will follow the else path.  At the completion of this sequence, all threads in the warp will implicitly re-synchronize, and then continue on in lockstep execution.  (In fact, the exact order of whether the if path occurs first or the else path occurs first is unspecified.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question, when control flow diverges at the `if` statement, the threads where `threadIdx.x != 0` simply wait to at the convergence point after the `if` statement. They do not go on to the `printf` statement until thread 0 has completed the `if` block.

Comment: Thanks for this comment because it helped me to understand the answer of Robert Crovella faster.